# Download images from byte array in json response

Tags: android, image, performance, picasso

what would be most efficient way to display a image received as bytearray in json response. I am currently using volley to download the response and use my own caching implementation. Is there a way to use any of the existing libraries like Picasso to display the images ?

[image: JSON response]

Answer (score 1):

The string is a [Base64](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FBase64&ei=Rt-2VO27L4i9ggSHgIPwCQ&usg=AFQjCNFxJAMXAr4Jc-0wQvhcp_q4nZlf5w&sig2=sOV66ApclXXMOT8mqRuLjw&bvm=bv.83640239,d.eXY) encoded byte array. Use [Base64.decode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html#decode(java.lang.String,%20int)) to decode it to byte[] and then construct a `Bitmap` from the byte[].

Comment: that right, am using it in a listview so I dont want to implement all the caching and performance code and want to make use of some existing libraries.

Comment: I never said you couldn't use an existing libraries. In fact, I recommended you use some additional external libraries, Base64. You can not expect Picasso to know how to parse your json object and base 64 decode the right field somehow.

Comment: should  I implement my own caching layer in this case. I am able to decode the Base64 byte array and display the images.